# Testing Where Any Of A Multiple Of Values Appears In A Range

Tags: excel-formula

One can generate a dynamic array of boolean values testing where a single value appears in a vector like so: `=range=value`. But is there a way to generate a dynamic array from one formula that tests where any of a multiple of values appear in the vector?

For example, in the data below, I can get the output I want in column J, which tests where the value "a" appears in my original range in column G with `=$G$2:$G$7=$I$2`. But if I try to test multiple values, say either "a" or "b", using the same method, I can't.

Such a solution would need to be scalable; my example ranges are small for illustration, but in practice I'd like to test where any of say 100 values exist in a range of 1000.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use isnumber(match()):

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A6,C1:C2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Had tried ISNUMBER and MATCH just with the ranges reversed. Thanks